# Add application to Fb Page from outside Fb, add tab for it and configure if with specific data?

Tags: configuration, facebook

I have a simple product catalogue for businesses. There is a catalogue's management interface for adding products. Each business has a unique domain name where all its products are listed.
I would like to extend catagloue's functionality and allow businesses to have their products listed on facebook.

Functionality of the facebook application:
- Each business can install application from catalogue's management interface (I would like to have a button that opens facebook in a new window and prompts user to authorize access to one of user's existing Facebook Pages)
- installing application adds a Tab on selected Facebook Page,
- by clicking on a Tab visitor of the Facebook Page is presented with a list of products specific for this business. Data for that page is dynamic and can be accessed with a REST call and presented as json or html.

We would like each business that have a product catalogue with us to install application and have it automatically configured to use specific domain name when requesting product data.

Is it all technically possible? Could you point me into the right direction on how to
 - install application from external website
 - configure that application with a parameter (perhaps passed in url when requesting application installation)
 - automatically add Page Tab for this application

Cheers,

Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But it'll be a little different from what you are thinking, i guess.
I recently implemented code to add a tab to a page programmatically, it is as follows(**in PHP**) : 
`$tabAdded=$facebook->api("/".$id."/tabs","post", array("access_token" => $access,
                "app_id" => $fbconfig['appid']));`
From the code we see that we need an **app id**, an **access token**, and the **page id**(`$id`). `$facebook` is an instance of the FacebookPHPSDK.

So here's how we can get the three things in question:

- First app id, you'll need to create a Facebook *page tab* app, select **Page Tab** in the app's Basic settings (where you can mention the page tab url. This url will have the content for a page tab.)
   You'll also need to enable ***website*** because you need to ask the user for necessary permissions (namely **manage_pages**). For your specific requirement you have to give the domain of the catalogue management app.
- Second page id and access token, once you have manage_pages permission you can query the graph api to get the pages of the user using : `api('me/accounts')` this returns data with page name, page category, page id, page access token for all the user's pages.

@thaddeusmt has already mentioned that you can't create new applications, and need to use the same app, you have to read the signed request and get the page id, and serve content. All that will be left to do is link your customer domains to the correct page ids.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301710/how-to-add-a-tab-to-a-facebook-page-with-graph-api) your help would be great

Comment: @JohnyStark, sorry I have not worked on the tabs api in a long time, so mostly forgotten most things, which means i would have to read the documentation again, search for answers again, etc. You are on your own on this one, I hope someone else gets to see your question and attempts to help you out, good luck. My tips: re-read the documentation (__carefully__), most of the details are already there, try searching for answers, you'll surely get it somewhere.

Comment: I got this :) thanx anyways

Answer (score 1):

You can install/uninstall (add/remove) application tabs to/from Pages using the Facebook API:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

You *cannot* create *new* applications, however. So you will need to use the same application for each Page.

The way you can show different content for each Page in the Tab (using the same application) is by checking the [Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/). This contains the ID of the Facebook Page. The code that serves up your application Tab can look at the Page ID and serve up the appropriate content for that Page.

I hope this helps get you on the trail. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. 
It's a two way process

1. First you have to get page_access_token through graphAPI.
   **www.facebook.com/?fields=access_token**
   This will return Page_access_token.
2. Use page access token and use post method
       **www.facebook.com/yourpageid/tabs/**
        Post Parameters:
                          **app_id= 'YourAppID'

                          access_token = 'access_token'**

That way you can add your facebook app into facebookPage.